# set the curser to the beginning of textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
MyEvent.prototype.sendMessage_ = function(input) {
  //input is this.find('#mytextarea');
  if (input.val().trim() != '') {
    input.val('');
    $('#mytextarea').focus();
  }
};

//...in the html....//
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Input Here" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

After empty a textarea with Jquery, the cursor is still at the end of the input, how could one move the cursor to the beginning of the textarea?

And in the view I have:

Comment: Try calling `.focus()` after - might reset it, not sure.

Comment: Thank you! tried .focus(), area got focused, however doesn't work for moving the cursor to the head.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$('#mytextarea').focus()`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$('#mytextarea')[0].focus()`

Comment: I don't think so, unless mytextarea was a class and there are a few of them present on the page. But, KBright's example uses the '#' selector, which is used for IDs.

Comment: Right, but if you look at `.focus()` in the jQuery docs, when you call it on a jQuery object, it refers to the `focus` event handler not the underlying Javascript `focus()` command. You have to access the DOM object with `[0]` to call the `focus()` command.

Comment: Docs: http://api.jquery.com/focus/ `$(selector).focus()` is used to trigger an event handler that is attached to the `focus` event.

Comment: @jwatts1980 unless the developer has overwritten the default behavior, Mike's answer will work as expected. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/MCc8t/

Comment: Ok. I'll concede that you guys are correct... as @Mike mentioned, the fact that the OP is referencing the DOM element by ID, and there is most likely to be only one element that needs to be focused. My previous attempts to use `focus()` in this way have failed for me, most likely because they were more complicated scenarios. +1 Mike.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried .focus(), but the cursor is still at the end of the textarea after I empty the textarea with $('#mytextarea').val('')

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('#mytextarea')[0].focus();
```